# u-boot compilation ERROR for beagle bone board (i am using Ubuntu platform)

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

After successful of hard coding the board id.
getting a error in building the U-boot in the 3rd step

i have tried to compile the U-BOOT and
I Got successful compile for the  below two steps.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} distclean
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} am335x_evm_defconfig
```

But in 3rd step that is ----

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC}
```

in the above  step i am getting ERROR as mentioned below

```
**cc1: error: unknown value ‘generic-armv7-a’ for -mtune**
Kbuild:43: recipe for target 'lib/asm-offsets.s' failed   
make[1]: *** [lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
Makefile:1588: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is the shell environment, in particular, what is `CC`? "*I Got successful compile for the below two steps*" -- Those steps do not do any compiling.  FYI U-Boot does not use/need the `ARCH` environment variable.  Suggest you study the "Building the Software" section in the **README** file in U-Boot source tree.

Answer (score 1):

am335x_evm_defconfig is a 32bit ARM board. You need to install the appropriate cross-compiler. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

When building you need to reference the cross-building tools:

```
make mrproper
make am335x_evm_defconfig
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build/gcc.html has more detail.